# Inserting in a list element

Tags: jquery

I have a list element like this:

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
   <li>Third</li>
```

I would like to insert an element of `<li>Ex</li>` before `<li>Third>/li>`. So far, everything I have been trying inserts `<li>Ex</li>` as a child of `<li>Second</li>`. I have used the following jquery methods:

insertAfter(), before(), after(), appendTo()... they all did the same thing. This is the what it looks like:

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second
       <li>Ex</li>
   </li>
   <li>Third</li>
```

but I want it like this:

```
<ul id="myList">
   <li>First</li>
   <li>Second</li>
   <li>Ex</li>
   <li>Third</li>
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Any pointers is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can do this by

```
 $('<li>Ex</li>').insertAfter('li:eq(<give childnumber here>)')
```

you want to inset after `<li>Second</li>` than use `eq(1)`

<sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: didn't do anything to it. Just stayed the same

Comment: .insertAfter('li:eq(<give childnumber here>)') does adds it like a child

Comment: @k.ken i dont understand ?? what you want exactly ?

Comment: This works perfect..I logged the `ul` html and it is correct! http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/Fh4vG/2/

Comment: I want what your jsfiddle is doing but it doesn't work for me. I have same exact thing you have. I have refreshed my page several times but it just doesn't appear.

Comment: @k.ken Have you closed your `<ul>`  with `</u>` Its not posted in your question..

Comment: yeah I did. I am sure all the tags are closed. The responses I get from my page is either it adds it like a child or it does nothing.

Comment: @k.ken something else must be interfering...can you link the page?

Comment: @k.ken check http://jsfiddle.net/yuCWE/ or `$('.myList:eq(1)')` should be `$('.myList li:eq(1)')`

Answer (score 1):

```
​$('li', '#myList')​​​.filter(function() {
     return $.trim($(this).text()) == 'Third';
})​.before($('<li />', {text: 'EX'}))​​​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/10/)

or if the index is always the same:

```
$('li', '#myList').eq(2).before($('<li />', {text: 'EX'}))​​​;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/JpvyX/13/)